# Can't install libcgmanager0 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management

I need to install `libcgmanager0` for some other package, however `sudo apt install install libcgmanager0` returns:

```
Package libcgmanager0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libcgmanager0' has no installation candidate
```

This site https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libcgmanager0 also shows an error and I just don't know what to do.

Is there any other source I can get it from or how do I solve this problem?

Comment: What is "some other package" and how are you trying to install it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the libcgmanager0 package by manual download from 16.04 LTS repository using commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnih/libnih1_1.0.3-4.3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnih/libnih-dbus1_1.0.3-4.3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cgmanager/libcgmanager0_0.39-2ubuntu5_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libcgmanager0_0.39-2ubuntu5_amd64.deb  ./libnih1_1.0.3-4.3ubuntu1_amd64.deb  ./libnih-dbus1_1.0.3-4.3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```